# Simple circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, photodiode, light-sensor

[image]

[image]

I am trying to figure out what the output voltage (V1) of this circuit is. Is the photodiode in reverse bias in this case, which means the current is flowing in (opposite of what is shown here)? Is this circuit better than the photovoltaic circuit?

I know the photodiode is in reverse bias in the second circuit, but if that were true for the first circuit as well, then what makes one better than the other?

Comment: Here is some basic reference on this topic: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/understanding-photovoltaic-and-photoconductive-modes-of-photodiode-operation/

Comment: The photodiode has zero bias in the 2nd circuit not reverse bias.

Comment: Per my calculations Vout across R in both circuits will be Ip * R. Most examples I came across google are using OpAmps to make a photo detecting circuit. I am confused since both equations have the same form then what reason makes one better than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that both your circuits are operating the photodiode with "zero-bias", the question's a good one.

One answer is that your first circuit (without the op-amp) has extremely high output impedance, any load connected to it will attenuate the signal amplitude. The transimpedance amplifier has close to zero output impedance, able to drive pretty much anything you connect to it, without influencing signal amplitude.

There's nothing stopping you from buffering the voltage across the resistor and diode, to obtain near-zero output impedance, on the right here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUOZEl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left is the classic transimpedance amplifier, and on the right is a buffered version of your resistor-only design. The first answer I gave above is now moot, since both of these designs have near-zero output impedance. So what's the difference?

My second answer to your question concerns biasing. On left, the voltage at the op-amp's inverting input is always very near zero volts, due to the [virtual earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_ground) principle. Therefore the voltage across the photodiode is also always zero, in spite of diode current rising and falling, and in spite of the output potential rising and falling. Thus zero-bias is always maintained. No significant dark current, or forward bias current ever flows, and all you get at the output is a voltage proportional to photocurrent.

On the right, though, the voltage across the resistor and diode *does* rise and fall as current around the diode/resistor loop varies, and consequently, the biasing state of the diode is *not* held steady. The voltage across the resistor may still be a function of photocurrent, but it is also influenced by factors such as the changing capacitance of the diode's depletion region, and changing impedance of the diode itself.